# Index register in cpu (Computer org. and arc.)

Tags: indexing, cpu, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

Can **index register** have **negative value**?
For example: at start **Xr is 0**, and then we need **to decrement it**? What will be the value of Xr?

Comment: Your question makes no sense if you don't tell us which specific CPU architecture you are talking about. Who's saying that architecture X even *has* an "index register" at all? Same goes for negative numbers and the decrement operation.

Comment: That being said: **Just try it out and see for yourself** what the result will be.

Comment: On class we work only with basic type of cpu (we never work with specific ones). But we know that it has an index register.

Comment: Well, and in class do they tell you if "basic type of CPU" can have a negative value in the index register? Because we don't know what architecture you're talking about. "Basic type of CPU" can mean anything.

Comment: Tnx... i get it. Profesor needs to tell us that spec. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A register can hold any value that fits in the number of bits it has. What makes the value negative or not is the way you treat it. The question you should be asking yourself is - does your basic CPU support signed arithmetic operations, and how does it encode them.

The common method you must have learned by now is 2's complement, so if a register holds a value of 0xffff (let's say it's 16 bit wide), then it can be interpreted as (2^16 minus one), or as (-1) - depending on who's reading it and how.
The term indexing is therefore a little ambiguous, as the value used will be determined by the type of operation - if you mean to use it within some computation - it depends if the operations you use are signed or not. If you mean to use it directly for memory addressing (if your CPU supports it) - again, it depends on what the CPU supports for this form on indexing.